# How to live stream large log file from remote server whenever it's updated to 100 of developers locally using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, live-streaming, polling

Problem statement is that there's a large log file which needs to be read once but needs to live stream logs whenever the file registers new entry. The file should be available to 1000 developers locally.

Comment: i think usually you would use something like logstash for this

Comment: One other option is to use message queue such as apache Kafka, zeromq, rabbitmq, or even redis. Publisher Subscriber architecture is better suited for this purpose. Highly recommend Kafka, which is built for this purpose.